# Date Field displayed as numbers - how to correct?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have sheet with 133 rows of Contract Start Date & End Dates. Over 70 seem to be in wrong format
When i do a VLOOKUP on dates to place them in a field some are coming out in 5 digit codes which don't correlate to the correct date, How do i fix this?

As an example in Column A3 the date is 12/10/2011, however the date is translated to 40828 in my LOOKUP column

Comment: Have you confirmed that they're all set to the same date format?

Answer (score 0):

40828 *is* the date 2011-10-12. Excel represents dates internally as the number of days since 1900-01-01.

Apply a date format to the cell(s) containing your LOOKUP formula and you should get your desired result.

Comment: I have tried different date formats and that hasn't worked. There seem to be an issue with source field for the date, as some are displayed correctly and others are not